# How many "sessions" can a router run without slowing down other devices on the network?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Qwest Actiontec Q1000 and I was just looking over my router/modem settings because sometimes when I play online with my PS3 I get lag when I have my computer connected to the internet, even though I am not downloading anything huge and have 12mb/s bandwidth. I have to disconnect the LAN cable to my computer and restart the router to get it to work half decently and it's annoying...I saw that my computer had 117 listed under the "No. of Sessions" column in the settings. Could this be what's causing my problem? What does this term mean exactly? How many sessions is normal and optimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of sessions usually means how many state entries are for this device for NAT. Normally it shouldn't matter how many sessions you have until you run out of local ports or out of router memory. If you see there 117 sessions for PC doing nothing then it looks like it is still doing something you don't know. There are plenty of programs you can install to your PC to see network usage in real time. The slowdown can be related with other parameters too like your uplink bandwidth (if your PC is still using that) which is usually less than 1 Mbps for DSL links.